# Static variable declaration in python classes

Tags: python, static-variables

What is the difference in the following two examples?

```
#Example 1
class Foo:
    
    var = None
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = 1
        
#Example 2
class Bar:

    var = None
    
    def __init__(self):
        Foo.var = 1
```

How does `var` vary between the two examples?

Is `Example 1` a static variable or is it an incorrect use of a variable declaration as a static variable?

Comment: Example 1 defines both a class attribute and an instance attribute. Example 2 defines only a class attribute, which `Bar.__init__` updates every time it is called.

Answer (score 2):

Simply

- `Foo.var` changes class state.
- `self.var` changes object state.

```py
class Foo():

  var = None
    
  def __init__(self):
    Foo.var = 1

class Bar():

  var = None

  def __init__(self):
    self.var = 1

print('Foo before', Foo.var)
print('Bar before', Bar.var)

foo = Foo()
bar = Bar()

print('foo', foo.var)
print('bar', bar.var)

print('Foo after', Foo.var)
print('Bar after', Bar.var)

Foo.var = 2
Bar.var = 2

print('foo after class changed', foo.var)
print('bar after class changed', bar.var)
```

output:

```
Foo before None
Bar before None
foo 1
bar 1
Foo after 1
Bar after None
foo after class changed 2
bar after class changed 1
```

About second question:

> Is Example 1 a static variable or is it an incorrect use of a variable declaration as a static variable?

Both `var`s are [static (or class) variables](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/class-or-static-variables-in-python). You able to call them without creating instance. (`Foo.var`, `Bar.var`)

```py
class Foo():

  class_variable = 'c'
    
  def __init__(self):
    self.instance_variable = 'i'

print('Class variable of class', Foo.class_variable)

try:
  print(Foo.instance_variable)
except Exception as e:
  print('This error happens when we call instance variable without creating instance')
  print(e)

instance = Foo()

print('Class variable of instance', instance.class_variable)
print('Instance variable of instance', instance.instance_variable)
```

```
Class variable of class c
This error happens when we call instance variable without creating instance
type object 'Foo' has no attribute 'instance_variable'
Class variable of instance c
Instance variable of instance i
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing examples from `Foo` and `Bar` to cars and trucks because I think a familiar object might be easier to grok:

```
#Example 1
class Car:
    
    age = None
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.age = 1

    def olden(self):
        self.age += 1
        
#Example 2
class Truck:

    age = None
    
    def __init__(self):
        Truck.age = 1
        
    def olden(self):
        Truck.age += 1

print("---Cars---")

accord = Car()
print(f"{accord.age=}")
accord.olden()
print(f"{accord.age=}")

camry = Car()
print(f"{camry.age=}")
print(f"{accord.age=}")

print("\n---Trucks---")
ram = Truck()
print(f"{ram.age=}")
ram.olden()
print(f"{ram.age=}")

f150 = Truck()
print(f"{f150.age=}")
print(f"{ram.age=}")
```

This prints

```
---Cars---
accord.age=1
accord.age=2
camry.age=1
accord.age=2

---Trucks---
ram.age=1
ram.age=2
f150.age=1
ram.age=1
```

What's happening is the cars' variables are being accessed with `self`, and since the Accord and Camry are separate car objects, they can age independently.

The trucks' variables are being access with `Truck`, so creating an F150 resets the `age` of the existing Ram.